# How to Compare my sql columns dynamically

Tags: compare, dynamic-columns

I am not able to get idea about the following requirement. The example table follows.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `did_fk` INT NULL,
  `adid_fk` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));

INSERT INTO test (id,name,did_fk,adid_fk) 
VALUES
(1,'Rajesh',1,1),
(2,'Neeli',2,2),
(3,'Satish',3,3),
(4,'Ganesh',4,5),
(5,'Murali',9,10);
```

Here I need to compare the "id" with _fk columns i.e. did_fk & adid_fk. The "id" should be equal to did_fk & as well as adid_fk. If any of them is not true, then I should get that row.Here I need to get the rows 4 & 5.Since "_fk" columns are not equal to "id" value.Problem is "_fk" columns are not fixed. But "id" name is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `Id` != `did_fk` OR `Id` != `adid_fk`
```

Comment: Thank you Stanislav ! But the columns are dynamic not static.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by dynamic in this case? Is it possible to provide some real example of how these columns defines? Thanks!

Comment: Here this table has only two "_fk" columns. I may have more for other table. I want write one dynamic script against the database, which should execute on any table for above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If your dynamic columns ends with _fk or some another suffix you can try to create SP like following

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetNonEqualFkValues`(IN tableName varchar(255))
BEGIN

DECLARE c_name VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR select column_name from information_schema.columns where column_name like '%_fk';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN curs;
SET @q = concat("SELECT * FROM ", tableName, " WHERE 1!=1 ");
get_col: LOOP
FETCH curs INTO c_name;
IF done THEN 
LEAVE get_col;
END IF;

SET @q = CONCAT(@q, " OR ", c_name," != id");
END LOOP get_col;

 PREPARE stmt1 FROM @q;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
END
```

And then invoke for concrete table like

```
call GetNonEqualFkValues('test')
```

The code isn't perfect, but it works for me and I think idea should be clear.